# Why does this JPQL fail with message "You have attempted to set a parameter at position x which does not exist in this query string"?

Tags: jpa, parameters, derby, named-query

I have the following named query:

```
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name ="Movies.findByTitle", query = "SELECT m FROM Movies m WHERE m.title = :title")
})
```

When I try to execute it as follows:

```
public List<T> findByTitle(String title) {
        return getEntityManager().
createNamedQuery("Movies.findByTitle").
setParameter("findByTitle", title).
getResultList();
    }
```

Then I get the following exception:

You have attempted to set a parameter value using a name of findByTitle that does not exist in the query string SELECT m FROM Movies m WHERE m.title = :title.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a correct parameter name.
You can see in your query the parameter is named "title" not "findByTitle".

`setParameter("findByTitle", title)`  change this to `setParameter("title", title)`